# WCF RIA Services / Linq-to-SQL: include property from foreign tables

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Say you have the following related tables (`Stores -> Categories -> Products`)

- Stores
- Categories
- Products

And I want to create a grid to edit `Products`. This is straightforward with RIA Services. But what if I also want to show `StoreName` from `Stores` and `CategoryName` from `Categories` in my `Products` list? The two extra columns should be readonly.

How can this be implemented?

*Update*: I'm trying to do this in it's simplest form. That is no ViewModel, only drag'n drop, code (if any) will go in codebehind. I'm using Ling2Sql and returning the default implementation for the GetProducts query.

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 0):

How do you have this set up? Are you binding to a ViewModel or just using the code behind? Is the web service sending back a list of Product LINQ object or are you doing something else?

There are a variety of options but it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to annotate your metadata file for the products and let the grid generate the columns for you.

For instance, your tables will probably look something like this:

```
Product
    int Id; 
    string ProductName;
    int CategoryId;

Category
    int Id;
    string CategoryName;
    int StoreId;

Store
    int Id; 
    string StoreName;
```

Now, when you create your service, you can include the 3 tables/entities from your domain model and have it generate the metadata file for you. In that file, annotate the objects correctly like so:

```
internal sealed class ProductMetadata
{
    [Key]
    [Bindable(false)]
    [Display(AutogenerateField=false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    [Display(Name="Product")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Bindable(false)]
    [Display(AuteogenerateField=false)]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Bindable(false)]
    [Display(AutogenerateField=false)]
    public CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

You can do the same to your other objects' metadata.

The only other thing you might have to do is add 2 other columns to your grid, and have them map to Product.Category.CategoryName and Product.Category.Store.StoreName

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response, but how does it actually know that it should include the Store information when I call the GetProducts? Does it always include all forrigin tables?, or is it some of the metadata that does it?

Comment: @Larsi: iirc, when you call myProduct.Category.Store (where myProduct is a product returned via your GetProducts method), RIA services will lazy load the category and store associated with the product.